# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets

Tags: python, numpy, binary, detection, kaggle

Im looking back the code analyzed through kekas for Kaggle's cancer diagnosis data. I definitely copied the code as it is, but there is an error like the title. I'll attach a link with the code.
https://www.kaggle.com/artgor/cancer-detection-with-kekas

The overall error contents are as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLWUF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No27s.png)

I think a problem has occurred in this area, but I don't know how to take action.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bngWb.png)

Thank you for reading it. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question. It causes getting more and better answers.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)